# How to define react compoent like Foo and Foo.Bar by TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I've already defined a react component by typescript, and I want to export it as a object so that I can add a new component on it.

```js
interface IFooProps {
  title:string
}

interface IBarProps {
  content:string
}

const Foo:React.FC<IFooProps> = ({title}) => {
  return <div>{title}</div>
}

const Bar:React.FC<IBarProps> = ({content}) => {
  return <div>{content}<div>
}


// I want to add Bar componet as one of Foo's value, and export Foo component

Foo.Bar = Bar; // Type Error!!

export default Foo
```

I hope I can use it like this:

```html
import Foo from './Foo'


const Content = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Foo title="title"/>
      <Foo.Bar content=“content”/>
    </>
  )
}
```

However, when I add Bar component to Foo, I get a type error. How should I fix it?

Comment: I don't want to use `any` type, it will miss many props type information

Comment: using variables (i.e. `const` / `let`) you will need to use `Object.assign`. With a `function` typescript should allow you to define properties within the same file as the function was created. [Here is an example of both](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-ppzjtr?file=App.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
import React from 'react';

const Foo = ({ title }: { title: string }) => {
  return <div>{title}</div>;
};

const Bar = ({ content }: { content: string }) => {
  return <div>{content}</div>;
};

Foo.displayName = 'Foo';

export default Object.assign(Foo, {
  Bar: Bar,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to combine the `<Bar/>` component and its prop types to the `<Foo/>` components `FC` and props declaration. Like so:

```
interface IFooProps {
  title:string
}

interface IBarProps {
  content:string
}

const Foo:React.FC<IFooProps> & {Bar: React.FC<IBarProps>} = ({title}) => {
  return <div>{title}</div>
}

const Bar: React.FC<IBarProps> = ({content}) => {
  return <div>{content}</div>
}

Foo.Bar = Bar
```

If you are going to have a bunch of subcomponents then it may be easier to write out your own interface to combine with but I think you get the idea.

Using reacts `FC` declaration can get tricky and sometimes it is easier to just declare your props explicitly instead. But the above should work I think.

Comment: Typescript will complain about `Foo` not containing a property called `Bar` when you first create it.

Comment: @JacobSmit Of course. Typescript will complain about anything where a type is specified and not used. That is the point of typescript. What point are you trying to make. If `Bar` is for sure going to be a part of `Foo` then I don't see why you wouldn't strongly type it as such.

Comment: The point is anyone using this is going to get a warning `Property 'Bar' is missing in type '() => JSX.Element' but required in type '{ Bar: React.FC<IBarProps>; }'`. This doesn't really solve the problem just swaps one type error to another.